# Get content from variable outside a function swift

Tags: function, variables, swift2

I am trying to obtain a user id and save it in the variable `selectedUserID`. 
The first print of `selectedUserID` gives me the correct value, but when I do the print outside of the function I get a null value. 
What could be the problem here?

```
var selectedUserID: String!;

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell

    print("Tableview selection is : " + currentCell.textLabel!.text!)

    selectedUsername = (currentCell.textLabel?.text)


    //Opzoeken wat het bijhorende ID is
    let query = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo:selectedUsername)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            // Do something with the found object

                for object in objects!
                {
                    self.selectedUserID = object.objectId
                    print("the destination is :" + self.selectedUserID!)
                }

    }

}
```

Comment: Adding the print outside the block will always return nil, it will be called before the block is completed. You should complete tasks that you require within the `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any idea how I can save the content of the var so I can send it to a different viewcontroller using a segue?

Comment: You will need to ensure that anything you want to happen after that variable has been set is called after the block has been completed

Comment: Do you have an example for my situation?

Comment: See my answer below :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wil try your code.

Comment: I have updated my answer, why are you looping objects from whats returned?

Comment: How did the adjustments go??

Comment: The segue code gives me the following error : "Expected declaration" http://ge.tt/7GhTEOS2/v/0?c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96053/discussion-between-zappidev-and-mathias-verhoeven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding any code outside the block declaring your `self.selectedUserID` will always return nil.

You will need to call the segue/other view from inside the block:
**(example using a segue)**

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            // Do something with the found object
            for object in objects! {
                self.selectedUserID = object.objectId
            }

            if selectedUserID == self.selectedUserID {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("<yourSegue>", sender: nil)
            } else {
                // Something is wrong
            }

}
```

Then you will need to capture the segue call, for example: **(Allowing you to pass the variable through)**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "<yourSegue>" {
        if let viewController: OriginsViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? OriginsViewController {
            viewController.userID = selectedUser
        }
    }
}
```